# Strange behavior of CustomEditText

Tags: java, android, custom-view

I created a custom `EditText` in order to fit the design of my app. The `EditText` should have a hint, and when it is focused, the hint should get colored and move to the right. When it is not focused anymore, the hint either gets located back at the left side, or, if text was written into the `EditText`, it stays at the right side and just changes the color back to the default hint-color.

Here is the code, which works just perfect:
(The LayoutWrapContentUpdater is further explained [here](https://github.com/ea167/android-layout-wrap-content-updater))

```
public class CustomEditText extends ConstraintLayout {

    private EditText textField;
    private TextView hint;
    private float hintSize;
    private float hintSizeFocused;
    private int hintColorFocused;
    private int hintColor;

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_edit_text, this, true);
        setClickable(false);
        textField = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_text_field);
        textField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus) {
                    focusHint();
                } else {
                    unfocusHint();
                }
            }
        });
        hint = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint);
        hint.setClickable(false);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditText, defStyleAttr, 0);
        hintSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hintSize, dpToPx(DEF_HINT_SIZE));
        hint.setTextSize(hintSize);
        hintSizeFocused = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hintSizeFocused, dpToPx(DEF_HINT_SIZE_FOCUSED));
        if(a.hasValue(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint)) {
            hint.setText(a.getText(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hint));
        }
        hintColorFocused = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hintColorFocused, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        hintColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomEditText_hintColor, getResources().getColor(R.color.def_hint_color));
        if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.CustomEditText_customBackground)) {
            Drawable background = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CustomEditText_customBackground);
            textField.setBackground(background);
        }
        if(a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CustomEditText_isPassword, false)) {
            textField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            textField.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
        }
        textField.setTextSize(a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomEditText_textSize, dpToPx(DEF_TEXT_SIZE)));

        a.recycle();
    }

    private void focusHint() {
        hint.setTextSize(hintSizeFocused);
        LayoutWrapContentUpdater.wrapContentAgain(this);
        hint.setTextColor(hintColorFocused);
        if(textField.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            moveHintToRight();
        if(textField.getPaddingRight() == 0) {
            textField.setPadding(textField.getPaddingLeft(), textField.getPaddingTop(), hint.getWidth() + dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE), textField.getPaddingBottom());
        }
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(textField, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }

    private void unfocusHint() {
        hint.setTextColor(hintColor);
        if(textField.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            moveHintToLeft();
            hint.setTextSize(hintSize);
            LayoutWrapContentUpdater.wrapContentAgain(this);
        }
    }

    private void moveHintToRight() {
        int horizontalDistance = textField.getWidth() - hint.getWidth() - dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE * 2);
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, horizontalDistance, 0, 0);
        anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if(textField.hasFocus()) {
                    ConstraintLayout l = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout);
                    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                    set.clone(l);
                    set.clear(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                    set.connect(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE));
                    set.applyTo(l);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
        });
        hint.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    private void moveHintToLeft() {

        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        ConstraintLayout l = findViewById(R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout);
        set.clone(l);
        set.clear(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT);
        set.connect(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.LEFT, dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE));
        set.applyTo(l);
    }
}
```

Attributes:

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
        <attr name="hintSize" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="hintSizeFocused" format="dimension"/>
        <attr name="hint" format="string"/>
        <attr name="hintColorFocused" format="color"/>
        <attr name="hintColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="customBackground" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="isPassword" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="textSize" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Example in XML:

```
<com.workoutlog.workoutlog.views.CustomEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/textfield_height"
        app:hint="@string/hint"
        app:hintSize="@dimen/hint_size"
/>
```

As already mentionen, this works. But there is one strange thing. I use these `CustomEditText`s in fragments. Now, when I have more of them in one Layout, type in some text into the last `CustomEditText`, go to another fragment and return to that fragment again (pushing the backbutton or calling `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()`), every `CustomEditText` in that fragment has written the text of the last `CustomEditText` when I opened the new fragment, and the hints don't work properly anymore (the text is written over the hints and they don't move to the right). When I type some text into another `CustomEditText` and no text into the last one, this doesn't happen. I can't explain why this happens.

The `CustomEditText`s are inside a layout inflated into a fragment.
It happens only when some text is typed into the LAST `CustomEditText` in a layout.

If you need further code, I can edit it.

**EDIT**

Wirling's answer works, thank you! But one thing still doesn't work: I can't move the hint to the right. When the state is restored, the hints are at the left side again and have the default textSize and textColor. I put this code into `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        getChildAt(i).restoreHierarchyState(ss.childrenStates);
    }

    if(!textField.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        hint.setTextSize(hintSizeFocused);
        LayoutWrapContentUpdater.wrapContentAgain(this);
        hint.setTextColor(hintColorFocused);
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(layout);
        set.clear(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
        set.connect(R.id.custom_edit_text_hint, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.custom_edit_text_constraint_layout, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, dpToPx(HINT_MARGIN_SIDE));
        set.applyTo(layout);
    }
}
```

The color and the size change, but I can't put it to the right side.

**EDIT2:**

I also get warnings everytime `childrenState` is passed to a method. For example:

```
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeSparseArray(childrenStates);
    }
```

Here I get the following warning:

`Unchecked assignment: 'android.util.SparseArray' to 'android.util.SparseArray<java.lang.Object>'`

Comment: you shouldn't need to add anything else to onRestoreInstanceState to restore state of the children. As for the warning you can ignore it with: `@SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})`

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem with the hint by removing `LayoutWrapContentUpdater.wrapContentAgain(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of duplicate view id's. Take a look at http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/

and add this code to your class:

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    SavedState ss = new SavedState(superState);  
    ss.childrenStates = new SparseArray();  
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {  
        getChildAt(i).saveHierarchyState(ss.childrenStates);
    }  
    return ss;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());  
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {  
        getChildAt(i).restoreHierarchyState(ss.childrenStates);
    }  
}

@Override
protected void dispatchSaveInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(container);
}

@Override
protected void dispatchRestoreInstanceState(SparseArray<Parcelable> container) {
    dispatchThawSelfOnly(container);
}

static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
    SparseArray childrenStates;

    SavedState(Parcelable superState) {  
        super(superState);
    }

    private SavedState(Parcel in, ClassLoader classLoader) {
        super(in);
        childrenStates = in.readSparseArray(classLoader);  
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        super.writeToParcel(out, flags);
        out.writeSparseArray(childrenStates);  
    }

    public static final ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState> CREATOR
            = new ClassLoaderCreator<SavedState>() {
        @Override
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source, ClassLoader loader) {
            return new SavedState(source, loader);
        }

        @Override
        public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return createFromParcel(source, null);
        }

        public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SavedState[size];
        }  
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But one thing still doesn't work. I edited the question.